# how to arrange li and remove li free space?

Tags: javascript, html, navbar

I want to remove free space between my li and arrange my li
the first pic is my code wants to change my navbar Free space like the second pic
and this is my styles i use in my codes

**First Image**
[this code must change to remove free space like the second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLLw3.png)

**Second Image**
[arrange and remove free space in navbar like this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26fhu.png)

```html
<head>
<style>
.test{
        margin: 0;
        width: 20.65%;
        padding: 0;
        height: max-content;
        display: unset !important;
        vertical-align: top;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .right{
    text-align: right !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    height: 500px!important;
}

</style>
</head>
   <ul class="test">
   <a class="text-bold" href="#">title</a>
   <ul class="list">
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test linkss</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
   </ul>
</ul>
<ul class="test d-block">
   <a class="text-bold" href="#">title1</a>
   <ul class="list">
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test linkss</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
   </ul>
</ul>
<ul class="test">
   <a class="text-bold" href="#">title</a>
   <ul class="list">
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test linkss</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
   </ul>
</ul>
<ul class="test">
   <a class="text-bold" href="#">title</a>
   <ul class="list">
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test linkss</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
   </ul>
</ul>
<ul class="test">
   <a class="text-bold" href="#">title</a>
   <ul class="list">
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test linkss</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
   </ul>
</ul>
<ul class="test">
   <a class="text-bold" href="#">title</a>
   <ul class="list">
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test linkss</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
   </ul>
</ul>
<ul class="test">
   <a class="text-bold" href="#">title</a>
   <ul class="list">
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test linkss</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

thanks

Comment: Have you tried flex with gap? you can type farsi I'm persian too.

Comment: yes i don't know ho i can remove that gap

Comment: @bardia riahi  you need to format your code properly after the `</head>` tag  you need to add the `body` tag  it is not good practice to put the `ul` tag inside another `ul`

Answer (score 1):

First, [remove all the browser default styles](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/):

```css
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* etc */
}
```

then set your `ul` element to display:flex and use property gap to set the gap between `li` elements inside that `ul`

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px; /* for example */
}
```

I can see you are using tailwind. If it didn't work you probably have some other classes that are affecting your code, please check for those.

Comment: use your browser inspect to find the exact classes that are affecting your elements. i ran your code here and there is no gap , so nothing is wrong with this code, what about .list class , you haven't included that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to put the `ul` tag directly inside another `ul`. Create a `li` inside `ul` and place the child `ul` inside it. like this example:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I added a `<div class="d-inline-flex">` and moved all your code into it.

```css
.test {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 170px;
  padding: 0;
  height: max-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.right {
  text-align: right !important;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  height: 500px !important;
}

.d-inline-flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-inline-flex">
  
  <ul class="test">
   <a class="text-bold" href="#">title</a>
    <li>
      <ul class="list">
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test linkss</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
   </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="test d-block">
   <a class="text-bold" href="#">title1</a>
  <li>
     <ul class="list">
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test linkss</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="test">
   <a class="text-bold" href="#">title</a>
   <ul class="list">
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test linkss</a></li>
      <li class="w-100 text-right"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
   </ul>
</ul>
<ul class="test">
   <a class="text-bold" href="#">title</a>
  <li>
     <ul class="list">
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test linkss</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="test">
   <a class="text-bold" href="#">title</a>
  <li>
     <ul class="list">
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test linkss</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="test">
   <a class="text-bold" href="#">title</a>
  <li>
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test linkss</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="test">
   <a class="text-bold" href="#">title</a>
  <li>
     <ul class="list">
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test linkss</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
      <li class="w-100"><a href="#">test link</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```